# Receber notificação quando um comentário do facebook for feito no wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou criando um blog em wordpress e quero fazer com que os comentários do facebook feitos na página da postagem gerem uma notificação na página do facebook do administrador da página.

Em um blog antigo, eu usei o plugin *"Facebook Comments Notifier"* e estava funcionando, então eu tentei pegar a sua estrutura e colocar junto com os scripts da nova versão do facebook, mas não funcionou, não sei se é por causa do plugin que não está atualizado ou se é a versão do facebook que está com algum *bug*.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Quando o comentário é realizado, ele pode ser normalmente visualizado acessando o Facebook, correto?